# The Date function thinks '5/1/16' means '5/1/1916'

Tags: javascript

... at least in the Google version. This manifests itself in a strange way. A CSV file containing a date like '5/1/2016' displays the date as '5/1/16', unhelpfully converting it to some internal date format, even though the original string is still in the file. Somehow uploading the file to Google Drive uses the '5/1/16' version. Then the Date function assumes we meant 1916.

Comment: Ok, and, what's your question? That sounds like a bug in... something. Something that isn't your code. So what do you want us to help you with?

Comment: since people live close to a hundred years, it's difficult to pick a meaning that won't discriminate against the very old or soon to be born...

Comment: when you say "displays the date", in what, how? if by excel, then you can remove formatting or save/view values (ctrl+shift+~) instead.

Comment: If you solve this problem the wrong way, they'll name a bug after you in about 80 years.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the Y2K bug?

Comment: Hacky solution, but something like this might work: https://jsfiddle.net/3pw47d79/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the original Date function should have raised an error if it saw a two-digit year But to respect code written in the last century, I guess it has to stay the same.

Similarly whatever excel does--switching back and forth between dates and strings--had been happening a long time. So, as the last code written the Google code that uploads a CSV file might try harder to get the original string out of the CSV file. The original string was something like "5/1/2016 10:00".